# Jquery drag&drop visual bug

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I try to use sortable list with drag and drop, but I have a visual bug in the drop event.
When I drag one line to another position, on the drop event, the line take the new position.
But the dragging line, visually return to its previous position.

I have this bug only on firefox.

You can try this on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvLyd2dy/4/).

How to delete this visual bug plz ?

This is my code :
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li draggable="true">test 1</li>
  <li draggable="true">test 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
[draggable] {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li.skeleton{
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  background: none;
}
ul li{
  height: 22px;
  margin: 10px 2px 0px 2px;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

JS (in $(document).ready(function(){}); ):

```
var current_element = null;
var skeleton = $('<li class="skeleton"></li>');

$('li').on({
  dragstart: function(e) {
    current_element = $(this);

    var dt =  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    dt.effectAllowed = "move";
    dt.setData("text", "Foo");            
  },
  dragend: function(e) {
    skeleton.after(current_element);
    current_element.show();
    skeleton.detach();
  }
}); 

$('li').on('dragover dragenter drop', function(e){
  if (e.type == 'drop') {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    current_element.trigger('dragend');
    return false;
  }
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  $(this)[skeleton.index() < $(this).index() ? 'after' : 'before'](skeleton);
  current_element.hide();

  return false;     
});
```

Comment: your jsFiddle works properly for me using FF 48.0.2 on windows

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm on linux FF 49. Other scripts I've tryed on the web, works fine. So, I think it's possible to remove this artefact.